# RP4 Ubuntu Server 22.04: Filesystem crash on USB plug/unplug

Tags: usb, raspberry-pi4, ubuntu-server, udev, epson

I'm running Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS on a Raspberry Pi 4 Model B with 4GB RAM. I'm booting Ubuntu via USB3 and everything works fine so far.
My issue is that at some point the filesystem crashes when I unplug/plug another USB device (It's an EPSON receipt printer). If I boot the system with the printer already attached everything works 100% of the time, but unplugging or plugging the printer at runtime results sometimes in a crash in the filesystem/access to the boot device.

How does the crash show up:
[image]
I'm connected via ssh and I can regularly type commands like `ls` and get the response. Then I unplugged and plugged the EPSON receipt printer multiple times and always executed a `ls` in between. At some point in time I always get `-bash: /usr/bin/ls: Input/output error`. And commands like `ifconfig` or `dmesg` are unknown. But the `pwd` command keeps on working. Please notice I did not unplug the SSD from which I booted. I already tried it with booting from an SD card and it seems there I don't get the problem. I already checked `journalctl`, but could find anything and I'm kinda clueless what's even going on.
PS: After a hard reboot everything works normally and it does not happen if I plug or unplug a regular USB stick, so it seems it's something about the EPSON printer?

UPDATE:
Executing `dmesg -w` gives this result. Please note Im only removing the EPSON printer, not the SSD.
**[image: strong text]**

Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: PS: Because it loses access to the filesystem I guess it can also not write down some logs which I can access after the hard reboot to get out any information. So it's really hard to debug or get any more information. I'm happy for any hint or idea of what to do or try out.

Comment: I found about this: https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/issues/3485
But for me it happens on any USB port and its not a hard drive.